# How to export cleaned data from a jupyter notebook, not the original data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have just started to learn to use Jupyter notebook. I have a data file called 'Diseases'.

**Opening data file**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Diseases.csv')
```

**Choosing data from a column named 'DIABETES', i.e choosing subject IDs that have diabetes, yes is 1 and no is 0.**

```
df[df.DIABETES >1]
```

**Now I want to export this cleaned data (that has fewer rows)**

```
df.to_csv('diabetes-filtered.csv')
```

This exports the original data file, not the filtered df with fewer rows.
I saw in another question that the inplace argument needs to be used. But I don't know how.

Comment: just export the filtered data, you are currently exporting the original dataframe. `df[df.DIABETES >1].to_csv....`

Comment: df[df.DIABETES >1] will give you the data, but isn't being assigned to any variable. Put it into some variable and export that with your .to_csv method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget assign back filtered DataFrame, here to `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('Diseases.csv')
df1 = df[df.DIABETES >1]
df1.to_csv('diabetes-filtered.csv')
```

Or you can chain filtering and exporting to file:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('Diseases.csv')
df[df.DIABETES >1].to_csv('diabetes-filtered.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! that was magic. I had been butting my head for the last couple of days. Finally I can move ahead.